# Android errors/warnings in emulator or on device: which can I ignore?

Tags: android, android-emulator

This question is similar to, but not the same as, [Logcat errors when running android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965339/logcat-errors-when-running-android-emulator).

When I run my app on the emulator, or even on the device, there are errors or warnings that I can apparently safely ignore. For example, see [Missing OpenGL drivers on Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114199/missing-opengl-drivers-on-android-emulator).

How can I accurately identify which errors/warnings are real and signifying a problem, and which can be ignored? I'm guessing the solution is either

1) a list of known messages/issues I can ignore, or

2) some sort of rule about which sources of the errors/warnings can be ignored (e.g. "if the logcat entry has tag X, you can ignore that")

I believe that living with spurious errors/warnings is dangerous, because you're more likely to miss real problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I accurately identify which errors/warnings are real and signifying a problem, and which can be ignored?

The same way you get to Carnegie Hall: practice, practice, practice.

> a list of known messages/issues I can ignore

There is no such list to the best of my knowledge.

> some sort of rule about which sources of the errors/warnings can be ignored

There is no such rule to the best of my knowledge.

Conversely:

- If there is a stack trace, and your code is in it, you definitely want to pay attention to it
- If you are experiencing other symptoms, examine LogCat to see what might be there that is related

> I believe that living with spurious errors/warnings is dangerous, because you're more likely to miss real problems.

In an ideal world, I would agree with you. In an ideal world, I'd weigh a bit less.